# how to edit html content inside tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to build a customized version of the [commenting plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/premium/comments/) available for tinyMCE.
I am using the [Annotations API](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/annotations/) to achieve this. Below is the code snippet currently being used to create a comment on some text selected by the user.

```
editor.ui.registry.addButton('annotate-alpha', {
    text: 'Annotate',
    onAction: function () {
        var comment = prompt('Comment with?');
        editor.annotator.annotate('alpha', {
            uid: `comment${commentId}`,
            comment: comment
        });
        if (comment == null || comment == '') {
            editor.annotator.remove('alpha');
        }
        editor.focus();
        commentId++;
    },
    onSetup: function (btnApi) {
        editor.annotator.annotationChanged('alpha', function (state, name, obj) {
            if (state == true) {
                commentsHandler('true');
            } else {
                commentsHandler('false');
            }
            btnApi.setDisabled(state);
        });
    }
});
editor.on('init', function () {
    editor.annotator.register('alpha', {
        persistent: true,
        decorate: function (uid, data) {
            return {
                attributes: {
                    'data-mce-comment': data.comment ? data.comment : '',
                    'data-mce-author': data.author ? data.author : 'anonymous',
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

this annotates the selected text correctly.

For example, in the below text if the user highlighted the text "features" and added a comment, the annotation is added and this is what the HTML looks like:

```
<p>Please try out the <span class="mce-annotation" data-mce-annotation-uid="comment0" data-mce-annotation="alpha" data-mce-comment="Comment 1" data-mce-author="anonymous" data-mce-selected="inline-boundary">features</span> provided in this full featured example.</p>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I5Tr.png)

Now suppose the user tries to highlight the entire sentence and adds a comment, the text "features" moves to the front of the sentence.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYjFi.png)
The updated HTML looks like:

```
<p><span class="mce-annotation" data-mce-annotation-uid="comment0" data-mce-annotation="alpha" data-mce-comment="Comment 1" data-mce-author="anonymous" data-mce-selected="inline-boundary">features</span><span class="mce-annotation" data-mce-annotation-uid="comment1" data-mce-annotation="alpha" data-mce-comment="Comment 2" data-mce-author="anonymous">Please try out the  provided in this full featured example</span></p>
```

I believe the existing `<span>` tag from the 1st comment is causing problems. A workaround can be that I check if the selected text has a previous annotation(span tag) and remove it before adding the new annotation but tinyMCE is loaded within an `iframe` and I can't access the HTML for manipulation.
How can I overcome this?